# How do I mark an IBOutlet as available for a specific iOS version

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

I am using the PDFKit native framework which is available for iOS 11 only and my project targets older iOS versions.
Xcode asked me to mark the whole `UIViewController` class as `@available(iOS 11.0, *)`

I'd like to handle viewing the PDF on older iOS versions in the same `UIViewController` using a different `UIView` that's going to use a `UIWebView` or a 3rd party library. How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you have two completely different ways of `controlling` the data, each with their own `view`, perhaps two separate `viewcontrollers` is a better solution? Make a base class (or a protocol + extension if you use Swift) and put your shared functionality there. Then make two  child viewcontrollers to present the data.

Comment: It's possible but I am asking if it's possible for me to use the same `UIViewController` without having to duplicate my UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set this condition for version specific execution on same view controller.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

    let pdfView = PDFView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "How", withExtension: "pdf")
    pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url!)
    self.view.addSubview(pdfView)

} else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

Comment: I can't do that for IBOutlets. The `PDFView` required by `PDFKit` is only available for iOS 11.

Comment: You can't set this condition for IBOutlets. Please check edited answer.